# Add field to mongo that contain the value of the document's length

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Sample document

```js
[{
  "_id": "1111",
  "name": "Dani"
},
{
  "_id": "2222",
  "name": "Guya",
  "address": "Arlozorov",
  "city": "Tel Aviv"
}]
```

Expected output, i want to add the length field

```js
[{
  "_id": "1111",
  "name": "Dani",
  "length": 2
},
{
  "_id": "2222",
  "name": "Guya",
  "address": "Arlozorov",
  "city": "Tel Aviv",
  "length": 4
}]
```

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the Question [Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Query

- `$$ROOT` is the document (system variable)
- convert it to an array
- take the array length and `$set`

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6282428f853f039c69b0f8dd)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": {"length": {"$size": {"$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"}}}}])
```

Comment: Try to avoid answering that question does not have any effort, as per the SO guideline  [on-topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: `$$ROOT` use and `$objectToArray` are complicated for new mongodb users, so its possible he didn't know what to search, its not like in mongodb documentation how to do this

Comment: I know there are solutions, but does he mention how to search and he can't able to do this? *he didn't know what to search,*, sooner this question might close because this does not follow the proper guideline. so my suggestion is to try to avoid that question asking like *i want this*, i have input and i want this output, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There's a fair amount of ambiguity in your description of `"length"`.  For example, if there is an array, does that count as one, or should the array contents be counted too?  Same for embedded/nested fields documents, etc.  And should the ever present `"_id"` field be counted?

Anyway, given your example documents and desired output, here's one way you could `update` each document with your `"length"` field.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "length": {
        "$subtract": [
          {
            "$size": {
              "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
            }
          },
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  "multi": true
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tNo--zlIuVG).